# How to use a member variable in a member function which is defined in a separate file

Tags: c++

userInput.hpp

```
#include <string>

class UserInput{
public:

    std::string rawInput;
    std::string parseUserInput;

};
```

userInput.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "userInput.hpp"
#include "stringManipulation.hpp"

using namespace std;

string branchCommand;

string parseUserInput(){

    removeWhiteSpaces(rawInput);

    return branchCommand;
}
```

I have created a class in userInput.hpp with the member function `parseUserInput` and I mean to define that function in userInput.cpp. However, when I try to use rawInput inside the definition, I cannot without making it so that `rawInput` is declared as `static`.

Is it possible to use the `rawInput` string in the function's definition which is in another file without making the `rawInput` variable static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you've declared `parseUserInput` as a string field in your hpp, not as a function.  Declare it as a member function by using paretheses.

```
std::string parseUserInput();
```

Second, in userInput.cpp you are defining a global function named `parseUserInput()`, not a member function.  To define the member function on the `UserInput` class, use the scope resolution operator `::`

```
std::string UserInput::parseUserInput() {
    ...
}
```

Finally, you should avoid [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) in your code.

Comment: avoiding `using namespace std;` in your code all together I don't normally enforce it as being 100% proper code, it is still ill advised to use it, however there are some cases that it is okay if it is within a function definition; but I would suggest to never use it at global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you thought about making a get function...

```
std::string returnRawInput() {return rawInput;}
```

you can then call this function to get the input...

Answer (score 1):

Your current class looks like this:

**userInput.hpp**

```
// Missing Header Guards Or #Pragma Once
#include <string>

class UserInput{
public:    
    std::string rawInput;        // Member Variable of UserInput      
    std::string parseUserInput;  // Member Variable of UserInput   
};
```

**userInput.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>                // Okay    
#include "userInput.hpp"           // Okay
#include "stringManipulation.hpp"  // Okay

using namespace std;   // Bad Practice

string branchCommand;  // non const local Global Variable - can be bad practice 

// Looks like a global function that is not a part of your class
string parseUserInput(){

    removeWhiteSpaces(rawInput);

    return branchCommand;   // returning global variable that isn't used?
}
```

Did you mean?

**userInput.hpp**

```
#ifndef USER_INPUT_HPP
#define USER_INPUT_HPP

#include <string>

class UserInput {
public:
    std::string rawInput; // Member Variable
    std::string parseUserInput(); // Now a Member Function that Returns a std::string
};

#endif // USER_INPUT_HPP
```

**userInput.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "userInput.hpp"
#include "stringManipulation.hpp"

std::string branchCommand; // Still a bad idea if not const or static

std::string UserInput::parseUserInput( /* should this take a string from the user? */ ) {
    removeWhiteSpaces( rawInput );

    return branchCommand; // ? ... Still not sure what you are returning.
}
```